# Tkinter Large Entry Box

Tags: python, tkinter

By default the entry box in Tkinter is only one row tall, is it possible to have a larger text box?

Example

```
text_write = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=50, textvariable=(text_to_write))
```

This will give you a text box that is 50 wide but only 1 row tall, is it possible to make the text box taller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Entry`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) widget is really just for one-line entries. For larger text boxes, use the [`Text`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) widget. This gives you a large, multi-line, text-wrapping text box. For scrollable text boxes, it is easier to use the `ScrolledText` widget.

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
self.textfield = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self, wrap=Tkinter.WORD)
```